# Coredata is not updated

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I wanted to update one record in my core data entity and I write code for it but the data is not updated .

There is Entity posts and it has data with id
i have to update the record for one particular id .

Here is function to update the record

```
 -(void)updateDataInDB:(NSString*)withID WithDes:(NSString*)newData{
     NSManagedObjectContext * context = [self getManagedContext];
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"News" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"postId == %@",withID];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    [fetchRequest setFetchLimit:1];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *arrResult = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    if(arrResult.count>0){
        NSManagedObject *news = [arrResult objectAtIndex:0];
        [news setValue:newData forKey:@"fullDesc"];


    }

   [self saveContext];
}
```

**Please Help if anything wrong**

Comment: Have you checked to see that `arrResult` is not empty or nil, and that there is no `error`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My core data contains duplicate records and i updated only first records so that the problem with update. After I updated all array records the code working fine.